# How to setup redis/sentinel replication/monitoring with docker on separate docker machines?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-sentinel

Let's say I have 3 separate machines:

```
redis$ docker-machine ls
NAME           ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
redis-master   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v1.10.1   
redis-slave1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376           v1.10.1   
redis-slave2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.103:2376           v1.10.1
```

I want to use `docker-compose` to easily deploy master or slave to one of those three machines. For now my docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
redis:
  image: redis:3.0
sentinel:
  image: redis:3.0
  command: "redis-server --sentinel"
```

How should I modify my docker-compose.yml file to make it work?
At the end I would like to be able to start containers like this for example:

```
$ NODE_ROLE=master docker-compose up # on master machine
$ NODE_ROLE=slave MASTER_ADDRESS=192.168.99.101:2376 docker-compose up # on slave machine 1
$ NODE_ROLE=slave MASTER_ADDRESS=192.168.99.101:2376 docker-compose up # on slave machine 2
```

I saw some repositories with redis + docker + sentinel setup, but all of them run all instances on same docker host...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look into using https://github.com/docker/swarm

Swarm allows you to treat multiple machines as a single docker engine. You can then let the swarm scheduler decide where to run the container, or use a constraint to put the container on a specific node.